# check the about-to-be-returned value in the debugger

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I find out the return value before returning while debugging in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studio)
>   [VS get returned value in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591086/vs-get-returned-value-in-c-code)

In Visual Studio 2010, is there a way to check the value that a method is about to return?  I often find myself changing code like:

```
return myComplexOp(someOtherComplexOp(foo));
```

to

```
var ret = myComplexOp(someOtherComplexOp(foo));
return ret;
```

just to make it easier to debug?  Is there an easier way?

Comment: +1; this bugs(!) me a lot too.

Comment: Here's a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/268048/can-i-find-out-the-return-value-before-returning-while-debugging-in-visual-studio) asking the same thing for VS (not just 2010) specifically for C#. The short answer seems to be no for C#, but yes for C++ (with some having trouble successfully doing it).

Comment: +1 just because I hate this too.

Answer (score 4):

With C++ code I am stepping out of the function (Shift + F11) and open Autos window (Debug, Windows, Autos). At this point it shows recently returned value like this:

[image: Debug, Windows, Autos]

It's not the most convenient thing, but it's still something. At least you can see the returned value without altering code as mentioned in original post.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable the `Registers` Windows, you can check EAX which should hold the return value.